# multi buttons on one javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

foreach fetch songs from database each audio have button to pause and play
all buttons of all songs works with first song only... when i press button of second or third song the first run ...  any solution ?

blade.php

```
    @foreach($songs as $song)
    <audio  class="player" id="player"  src="{{asset('audios/'.$song->song)}}" type="audio/ogg" > 
   </audio>
        <div class="player-control">
            <button id="{{$song->id}}" class="playerbutton play btn btn-outline-info" 
    onclick="playmusic(this)" ><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
    <button id="pause" class="playerbutton pause btn btn-outline-info" 
    onclick="pausemusic(this)"><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

js.file

```
var player=document.getElementById("player");
  function playmusic()
  {
    
    player.play();

  }
  function pausemusic(elem)
  {
    player.pause();
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `var player=document.getElementById("player");` you select only one audio element.
If you add a unique song id to the buttons and audio tag like this:

```
@foreach($songs as $song)
<audio  class="player" id="player-{{$song->id}}" ... </audio>
<div class="player-control">
    <button data-song-id="{{$song->id}}" ... onclick="playmusic(this)" >...</button>
    <button data-song-id="{{$song->id}}" ... onclick="pausemusic(this)">...</button>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Then you may select a bound audio element directly inside the function:

```
  function playmusic(e)
  {
    var songId = e.dataset.songId,
     player = document.getElementById("player-" + songId);
     player.play();
  }
  function pausemusic(e)
  {
    var songId = e.dataset.songId,
     player = document.getElementById("player-" + songId);
    player.pause();
  }
```

Comment: i got an error (Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined)

Comment: Oouch. Please change as follows for each function: onclick="playmusic()" => onclick="playmusic(this)" and e.target.dataset.songId => e.dataset.songId

Comment: but  what is this  (data-song-id)?

Comment: It's a data attribute that stores a unique song-id value. Using this value you may select a correct audio player associated with this song by id `document.getElementById("player-" + songId)` .